# Question concerning correspondence in automatic sequences

Tags: number-theory, automata

If I have an automatic sequence, like the thue-morse sequence:

$0\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and $1\rightarrow \{1,0\}$ initialized with $0$

And another sequence:

$1\rightarrow \{1,0,1\}$ and $0\rightarrow \{0,0,0\}$ initialized with $1$.

How can I figure out when both sequences have a $1$ at a given position?